# Qgis simple line vertex geometry and Z values

Tags: qgis

QGIS 2.8.4 - utility networks
postgres 9.3/postgis 2 database

The linear network is made up of simple lines joining points that have different z values. For each feature in the line layer's table I would like there to be a column for the start point and a column for the end point populated with the z values from the point layers.

I would like to update a column in a the line attribute table where the first vertex of a simple line is updated with a numerical value from another point layer to which it is snapped.
Then do the same for the second vertex and get the value from the point later to which the second line point is snapped.

From there a simple calcule to get the slope.for each line in the network.

Would ST_startpoint and ST_endpoint be the right way to go?